# Hide field from tree view base on the condition, Odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-14, odoo-15

I want to hide field from tree view depends on the condition. I tried some techniques, but didn't work for me. Currently I can hide just value not all column. I want to hide whole column.

This is my tree view. And this code just hide the value not column.

```js
<record id="view_tai_approval_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">tai.approval.tree</field>
        <field name="model">tai.approval</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <tree create="false">
                <field name="tai_reference"/>
                <field name="tai_project_name"/>
                <field name="responsible_name"/>
                <field name="tai_purchase_date"/>
                <field name="tai_supplier_name"/>
                <field name="state" class="bg-danger" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'unapproved')]}"/>
                <field name="state" class="bg-success" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'approved')]}"/>
                <field name="state" class="bg-warning" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'pending')]}"/>
            </tree>
        </field>
</record>
```

Actually, as you can see in the code, I just want to change the colors depends on the states. So is there any simple solution for this?

Comment: I tried this one and still not working, "<field name="state" class="bg-danger" attrs="{'column_invisible': [('parent.state', '!=', 'unapproved')]}"/>"

Comment: Do you want to change the color of the whole row or just the color of the state field text?

Comment: Just the state field text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Odoo allows you to change the behavior of the text based on the attributes of the corresponding record.

[This](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/es/developer/howtos/backend.html?highlight=decoration#id3) documentation is for tree views, but what they describe also works for fields.

```xml
<record id="view_tai_approval_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">tai.approval.tree</field>
    <field name="model">tai.approval</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <tree create="false">
            <field name="tai_reference"/>
            <field name="tai_project_name"/>
            <field name="responsible_name"/>
            <field name="tai_purchase_date"/>
            <field name="tai_supplier_name"/>
            <field name="state"
                decoration-danger=="state != 'unapproved'"
                decoration-success="state != approved'"
                decoration-warning="state != 'pending'"/>
        </tree>
    </field>
</record>
```

Comment: Thank you it works. But Is there any way to change bg color?